# ¿como desencadenar una accion al pulsar un textfield?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Buen dia a todos, tengo una consulta. ¿Puedo desencadenar una acción al presionar sobre un textfield? Estoy trabajando con netbeans y javafx, además para hacer la interfaz me estoy apoyando de scenebuilder. Trate de poner el código sobre el método onAction del textfield pero no funciona.

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo un caso de prueba con una método referenciado es algo simple usamos el listener de MousePresed sobre el label, también se puede usar el MouseReleased
Simplemente llama tu label, textfield u otro elemento del FXML a tu clase Java y usa uno de los dos métodos que te dejo abajo.

```
@FXML
private Label label;
//usamos el metodo onMousePressed sobre el label.
label.setOnMousePressed(evt->{
if(evt.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
   //haz algo con el click derecho.
}
});
```

Ya si prefieres usar los listener de la manera regular te dejo el método

```
label.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {
    if(event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
    //Puedes hacer aqui lo mismo que en el metodo referenciado
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hola, agrega alguna explicación del código para mejorar la calidad por favor.

Comment: Con gusto me podrías dar una explicación breve de como debo de explicarme, pero el código, a mi parecer no tiene ninguna falla, con gusto estoy abierto a aprender mas acerca del tema